# Good reference for C++ iostreams?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am struggling understanding C++ iostream library -> "What and why only" . I found a library 
at IBM named "IBM C/C++ Legacy Class Libraries Reference" , which can seen here:

[IBM C/C++ Legacy Class Libraries Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/install/compiler_pubs.htm)  
[Alternate link](http://www.bluefern.canterbury.ac.nz/UCSC%20userdocs/ForUCSCWebsite/C/AIX/legacy.pdf)

i want to ask that , is this good reference for c++98 iostream (it goes with standard?)?
or any other reference? . 
i am looking for deep and good tutorial on it, why things happen etc .

I can't buy c++ iostream and locales book ( pocket problem:) ) , so don't tell me to buy it.

Comment: The word "legacy" when applied to C++ generally means "pre-standard stuff that nobody should ever look at, except when trying to bring antediluvian sources to life". Do not ever look at the "legacy" documents, only at the "standard" documents. Besides, it's a reference, not a tutorial. It only says "what", not "why".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree it is difficult. Try the following book.

Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales: Advanced Programmer's Guide and Reference 
Angelika Langer & Klaus Kreft 
Addison-Wesley, January 2000 
ISBN: 0201183951

Comment: he already said : `I can't buy c++ iostream and locales book ( pocket problem:) ) , so don't tell me to buy it.`

Comment: Perhaps he could find it at the library.  Or, if he lives near a University he could even use one of their libraries during public hours.

Comment: The book was released in 2000. now that it is 2018 is it outdated or is it still relevant?

Comment: @WARhead: Yes, it is still relevant. The iostreams library did change almost not at all since then.

Answer (score 6):

[Here is what you are looking for.](https://archive.org/details/TICPP2ndEdVolTwo)

Its Thinking in C++ 2nd Edition Volume 2 by Bruce Eckel.

Comment: Probably the best choice given the boundary condition.

Comment: The [link](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) is broken. Do you have a new link?

Answer (score 5):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp is considered a very good reference.

Answer (score 2):

The reference you cite is definitely pre-standard: the classes it 
documents aren't templates; they don't support locale (since they
pre-date locale by at least five years); there are classes which don't
exist in the standard (all those with `_withassign`) or are deprecated
(`[io]strstream`); on the other hand, classes from the standard
(`stringbuf`, many of the manipulators) are missing.

Most of the overall philosophy is unchanged; in particular, the use of
the strategy pattern to decouple sinking and sourcing from formatting
and parsing, and to allow customization of sinking and sourcing.  And I
don't know of any free documentation about the overall philosophy, or
how to actually use the streams (the Wikipedia page on `iostream` is a
disaster), so short of purchasing a good book, this may be the best
source you can find.  Just be aware that most of what it describes has
changed significantly.  Only the overall philosophy (use of `streambuf`,
manipulators to control format, etc.) remains.  The lack of good, easily
available tutorial information is a serious lack, because in projects
where someone knows iostreams well, most `streambuf` and most
manipulators will be defined within the project, and not be standard
ones.

And for what it's worth: `streambuf` is definitely not defined in `ios`
which becomes two classes, `ios_base` and `basic_ios<T>` in the
standard), although some of the classes derived from `ios` may contain
an instance of a class derived from `streambuf`.  (In modern
implementations, `ifstream` and `ofstream` typically contain a
`filebuf`, for example.  I don't think that this was the case in the
traditional iostreams, however, and in this case, the only reason for
the containment is to avoid a dynamic allocation; all communication
between the two still takes place through the `streambuf*` in
`basic_ios`.)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at chapter 15 *Input/Output Using Stream Classes* and chapter 16 *Internationalization*, in **The C++ Standard Library**, Second Edition, by Nicolaï M. Josuttis, published  march 2012. A book compliant with the recent C++11 standard.
I know you said you could not purchase a book, but this one is a foremost reference in the domain and you could probably borrow it from a good library or from a colleague.

Comment: it's a tutorial man not reference to be precise :)